# Strip a parent folder from a zip file

Tags: javascript, zip

Given a zip file with the structure:

```
  /unwantedParentFolder
    /wantedFolder/**/*
    /wanted.files
```

Is there an easy way to 'restructure' it so that `/unwantedParentFolder` is stripped. e.g.:

```
  /wantedFolder/**/*
  /wanted.files
```

Ideally using Javascript alone, although I could probably make common linux commands work.

---

For some further information: I am gluing together Gitlab and AWS CodeBuild using a lambda (hence the Javascript). Gitlab have an api to fetch the current repo files as a zip, and CodeBuild can build from a zip. Unfortunately Gitlab takes the view that the repo should be in a folder in the root, while CodeBuild wants the repo to be the root.

At the moment the best I've got is to package up the linux zip utilities, unzip everything into the temp folder, move one folder up and rezip. But it seems a bit hackey and I'm nowhere near a zip expert so I thought I'd put it out there...

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite having found it, I obviously didn't take a hard enough look at the documentation of JSZip (as suggested by @LGSon)!

https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html does exactly this:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('file');
const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(data);
const rerooted = await zip
  .folder('unwantedParentFolder')
  .generateAsync({ type:"nodebuffer" });
fs.writeFileSync('fixed.zip', rerooted);
```